# Is the marriage between these Doctor Who characters ever consummated?

Tags: doctor-who

I tried to leave the title as non-spoiler-ish as possible.  If enough time has passed that a spoiler in the title is permitted, please feel free to edit.

At the end of Season 6 of Doctor Who, we see...

> The Doctor marry River Song.

But we don't see them spend much time alone; at least not as far as I've watched so far.

Is their marriage ever consummated?

Comment: I realise it's not a full answer but River puts out such a flirty vibe towards the Doctor in just about every encounter we see that I'd be surprised if they haven't (not that flirtation necessitates sex, of course).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**It is, presumably off-camera in one of their many romps while River is "imprisoned" in the Stormcage facility for the murder of the Doctor.**

> River was sentenced to twelve thousand consecutive life sentences in the Stormcage Containment Facility in the 52nd century for the Doctor's murder. (TV: The Time of Angels, The Pandorica Opens) She served the sentence to make the Silence believe him dead, but starting with her first night, often escaped to spend time with her husband, then returned to her cell. (TV: First Night) **[TARDIS Data Core -> River Song](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/River_Song)**

Talking to Dorium at the end of the Wedding of River Song,

> DORIUM: "And Doctor Song, in prison all her days?"
>
> DOCTOR: "Her days, yes. Her nights… well, that's between her and me, eh?"

Comment: Hmm, that quote is really neither definitive nor suggestive. :| However, I haven't watched the River Song episodes yet so I know I don't have the full context. Did Doctor/River Song actually have chemistry?

Comment: Oh yes, they definitely appeared to be in love. As much as I have ever seen the Doctor love anyone.

Comment: A quote/transcript from one of the several episodes in which this happens would be much more conclusive. While the Wikia is essentially correct, it doesn't contain any of the emotional clues that would show this to be the only possible conclusion.

Comment: Talking to Dorium at the end of the Wedding of River Song, "And Doctor Song, in prison all her days?"

"Her days, yes. Her nights… well, that's between her and me, eh?"

Comment: I don't remember the 12000 consecutive lifetimes sentence. Was this ever said on TV?

Answer (score 8):

The [2015 Christmas Special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Husbands_of_River_Song) depicts

> River spending 24 years with the 12th Doctor on the planet Darillium. The episode ends with the text: "And they both lived happily ever after."

If it wasn't consummated before, it is now.

Answer (score 7):

In The Impossible Astronaut she says "Don't worry, I'm quite the screamer. Now there's a spoiler for you!" Proof enough for me.

Comment: Also "Why do you have handcuffs?" "... Spoilers!"

Answer (score 2):

In the Demon's Run episode (forgive me not remembering the episode's actual title) when he finds out who she really is, the doctor is like, "And you and I.... oh!" in a very suggestive way. The season 6 short extras (Night and the Doctor) also give a glimpse to the fact that the two do see each other more often than we see, and go on real dates, not just adventures. I definitely think that yes, the marriage in consummated. ;)