# With how many companions/associates does The Doctor have sex at least once?

Tags: doctor-who

> ROSE: There's five of us now. Mum, dad, Mickey... and the baby.
>   THE DOCTOR (taken-aback): You're not...?
>   ROSE: No. (Laughs). It's mum.
>   The Doctor laughs with some relief and looks over at Jackie.
>   <sub><sub>[Doomsday transcript](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=7648)</sub></sub>

Can I infer from this that The Doctor thought that Rose was pregnant with his child because Rose was just sucked into parallel universe and he didn't know that Rose was there for 3 months? Actually, I automatically inferred that when The Doctor said "You're not...?"

Other than that, I have seen The Doctor kissing Rose, Amy, Martha, Elizabeth I, River Song in the new Doctor Who (2005). While it is clear that

> Elizabeth I and River Song were his wife

they won't be counted as his companions (correct me if I am wrong).

Also, it seemed like The Doctor had sexual affair with Marilyn Monroe.

> RORY: Your phone was ringing. Someone called Marilyn. Actually sounds like THE Marilyn.
>   AMY: Doctor?
>   DOCTOR: Tell her I'll phone her back. And that was never a real chapel.
>   <sub><sub>[A Christmas Carol transcript](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=555&t=7688)</sub></sub>

But, I don't know if she was The Doctor's companion/associate. Maybe, someone who has watched the original Doctor Who can enlighten.

I got a new name when River Song accused The Doctor in *The Husbands of River Song*:

> The Doctor: So, King Hydroflax?
>   River: Oh, how many times? I married the diamond.
>   The Doctor: So you say.
>   River: Elizabeth I.
>   The Doctor: Ramone.
>   River: Marilyn Monroe.
>   The Doctor: Stephen Fry.
>   River: **Cleopatra!**
>   <sub><sub>[The Husbands of River Song transcript](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=555&t=24374)</sub></sub>

Was Cleopatra his companion/associate? I think, I have heard that she was indeed his companion/associate. Possibly, I have seen her in a dinosaur episode.

Also, I haven't watched the original Doctor Who of 60s.

How many companions/associates has The Doctor brought to the bed at least once?

Comment: I don't know how this can possibly be answered given the amount of lies the Doctor tells.  He only seems to fall for one companion, although many companions and non-companions fall for him, and the only long-term-ish relationship we ever see him in is hideously complicated by it happening out of order.  The only time sex is brought up in a non-farcical manner (discussing Amy's baby) both he and the questioner treat it like a subject he avoids at all costs.  What makes you think the answer isn't zero?

Comment: @Radhil Well, he must have had sex with SOMEbody in order to have a granddaughter (and shush, don't mention Looms ;-) ) There were a lot more sex references during Matt Smith's era, partly because Moffat wants to cram in random references to everything he could possibly think of that sounds cool, like those scenes at the start of *The Impossible Astronaut*.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - point on Susan, but every sex reference I could recall was treated tongue in cheek or a one-off gag, endless flirting with Matt Smith included.  Thus my comment - was trying to clarify the different assumptions, given my takeaway (as in your answer) that they dodge any direct implications for kid's sake, and didn't want to just downvote without thinking about it.  The show gives more serious thought to the idea that he mostly abstains, given companion relationships are already quite complicated.

Comment: I always thought the Doctor's response to Rose about the baby was not anything to do with potential paternity, but merely the reaction of a good friend to the possibility of great news.

Comment: @Radhil References to Elizabeth I are more of a *recurring* gag than one-off. (Still tongue-in-cheek though)

Answer (score 14):

### River Song and at least one or two more.

From [Is the marriage between these Doctor Who characters ever consummated?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37650/31394) it seems that the Doctor did consummate his relationship with River Song. (But given that "the Doctor lies", of course, who knows.)

He's also been married to Queen Elizabeth I and Marilyn Monroe, but there's no in-canon confirmation of whether or not those marriages were ever consummated. And before you say "they were married, why wouldn't they", the answer could well be "no" in each case:

- He married Elizabeth in *The Day of the Doctor* but then swooped off to save Gallifrey, and presumably (what with the "time streams being out of sync") forgot all about the whole thing afterwards, everything from when his future incarnation stepped out of the time vortex. Perhaps that's why she called him her enemy in *The Shakespeare Code* - because he never came back.
- He married Marilyn Monroe in *A Christmas Carol*, but it seems he left the same evening, so maybe they never had time to ... get up to anything.

Then there's Nefertiti in *Dinosaurs on a Spaceship*:

She refers to "what we've just been through", but this doesn't necessarily suggest they've had a sexual relationship - she could be referring to the gient alien locust attack they just stopped together, and her attempted seduction is more like Amy's in *Flesh and Stone* than that of a long-time lover.

There's also an unnamed woman in *The Impossible Astronaut*:

> We pan again to see a painting of the DOCTOR in a god-like pose in the clouds, He is holding a trident on his right hand and his left is on his hip. A red swath of cloth is all that protects his modesty.
>
> MAN: (through door) Doctor!
>
> The MAN finally bursts through the door, sword drawn. Two others are behind him.
>
> MAN: Where's the Doctor?!
>
> The artist, a WOMAN, laughs nervously.
>
> WOMAN: Doctor who?
>
> There is a muffled sneeze and the MAN uses the tip of his sword to lift the hem of the WOMAN’S dress. A naked DOCTOR peers out.
>
> DOCTOR: You know, this isn't nearly as bad it looks.
>
> <sub>-- [The Impossible Astronaut](http://jpgr.livejournal.com/118043.html)</sub>

As for your quote from *Doomsday*, the Doctor's relief could equally well be interpreted as relief that Rose hadn't found someone else. I don't think it suggests that there was a sexual relationship between him and Rose at that time, especially since it looks like they'd never actually expressed their love for each other before this very scene.

---

We really have no way of knowing the full answer to this question, because although the Doctor does [a lot of kissing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuM6fjAoNCw), **there's very little mention of sex in the show.** It's meant to be reasonably child-friendly, after all. If you want to see sex, go and watch *Torchwood* instead.

Comment: What about Cleopatra? It was implied that they have a history in _Dinosaurs on a Spaceship_.

Comment: @Gallifreyan But was it a *sexual* history? I don't remember well enough exactly how they interacted (though I do remember she went off with Riddell instead), and the transcript isn't giving me enough of an idea of their body language.

Comment: My bad, it was Nefertiti. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tz2lj7EmkdM), make of it what you want :)

Comment: @Gallifreyan Thanks, added in a section about her.

Comment: Re: Elizabeth in *Day of the Doctor* - Because of crossed timelines, he forgot all that happened with his other selves. Since his wedding with Elizabeth was in the middle of that, I took it that he forgot that too. Though, in *The Beast Below*, "Liz 10" implies that he & Elizabeth had a sexual relationship

Comment: @Adeptus That's a very good point. Edited, thanks!

Comment: There's also 10's brag in End of Time to Ood Sigma that he married Queen Elizabeth and that they can't call her the Virgin Queen anymore, but then again, the Doctor lies...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is specifically about companions, and for some reason, you personally discount River as a companion because they were eventually married.

If this is the case, the answer is **none**.

There was definitely unspoken romantic love for *Rose*, but she was trapped in the parallel universe before that could even be admitted. Anything she subsequently got up to with the Doctor's clone doesn't count.

Martha fancied The Doctor but it was unrequited. He chose Donna deliberately as his next companion to avoid that sort of thing happening again, as she demonstrated physical revulsion at the idea of "mating" with him, an alien.:

> DOCTOR: I just want a mate!
>   DONNA: You're not mating with me, sunshine!
>   DOCTOR: A mate. I want a mate.
>   DONNA: Well, just as well, because I'm not having any of that nonsense. I mean, you're just a long streak of nothing. You know, alien nothing.
>   DOCTOR: There we are, then. Okay.
>   DONNA: I can come?
>   DOCTOR: Yeah. Course you can, yeah. I'd love it.

There was definitely a bit of frisson between The Doctor and Amy but she stayed loyal to Rory and The Doctor respected that relationship.

The Doctor may have feelings for Clara, but his regeneration from the youthful Eleven to the physically older Twelve was, evidently, to address that:

> DOCTOR: I've made many mistakes, and it's about time that I did something about that. Clara, I'm not your boyfriend.
>   CLARA: I never thought you were.
>   DOCTOR: I never said it was your mistake.

In classic Doctor Who, there was really no mention of romance for The Doctor at all. It was a shock when the Eighth Doctor kissed Grace (who declined his offer to travel with him in the TARDIS so was never really a *travelling* companion). A joke is made of the notable shift in this since the reboot when the War Doctor sees Ten kissing and asks Eleven:

> WAR DOCTOR: Is there a lot of this in the future?
>   ELEVEN: It does start to happen, yeah.

Had you broadened the scope beyond the traditional definition of 'companion' and asked how many sexual relationships The Doctor has had *that we know of*, the answer would be **three**:

- His unnamed first "wife" (the mother of his children and Susan Foreman's grandmother)
- Elizabeth I (second wife)
- River Song (third wife)

His offspring confirm that the first marriage was consummated; innuendos by the Tenth Doctor in both *Day of The Doctor* and *The End of Time* confirm that the second marriage was also consummated. Multiple innuendos from River along with the fact they spent 24 years together on Darillium confirm his third marriage was legit as well.

An incident in which The Doctor was caught naked with a daughter of King Charles I was explained away by the Doctor when he said "it isn't as bad as it looks" (it appears she may just have been painting him as a naked cherub).

Answer (score -1):

Please remember, the Doctor is not a human. He is a Gallifreyan. Superficial appearances do not make the mutually alien species sexually compatible.  So, no sex.